# VBA Find & Replace Row based on reference, if not found then paste at row at bottom

Tags: excel, vba

I'll try to explain this best as I can, and I attached an example pic of what I'm looking for help on.

Sheet 1 represents new data that comes into the workbook, Sheet 2 represents older data saved on the work book. I would like to run a script that replaces the whole row of data in Sheet 2 from Sheet 1 based on its matching reference. If Sheet 1 has an entry that does not find a matching a reference in Sheet 2, it then pastes the new value as the last row. This would ideally run as a loop until the last row of Sheet 1.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read in the [help] how to ask effective questions on the site. You'll notice that a certain amount of effort on the part of the asker is expected - this is neither a free code-writing nor a tutorial service. You can use the [edit] link below the question to add the code you've tried. Please point out at what specific point it's failing and describe in detail how it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

I tried working on it & come with this code. Hope this helps.

```
Sub insert()

Dim i As Integer
lastrow = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'SheetTwoEmptyRow = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim rgfound As Range




For i = 1 To lastrow
Set rgfound = Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A500").Find("A" & i)
If rgfound Is Nothing Then

Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i, "C" & i).Copy _
Destination:=Worksheets("sheet2").Range("E" & i, "G" & i)

Else
'do nothing

End If
Next i

End Sub
```